# apoc trigger to send newly created neo4j node to elasticsearch using apoc.es.put

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to write a cypher query to add a trigger using apoc, so that when a new neo4j node is created, the node gets automatically indexed into elasticsearch using apoc.es.put.

I have written the following cypher query:

CALL apoc.trigger.add("newNode","UNWIND {createdNodes} YIELD n CALL apoc.es.put('localhost','neo4j_index','protocol','1',null,{number:'4',title:'title',type:'type'})  RETURN null",{phase:'after'})

but i get the following error

Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError
Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: Error executing triggers {newNode=Invalid input 'Y': expected whitespace, comment, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR or AS (line 1, column 23 (offset: 22))
"UNWIND {createdNodes} YIELD n CALL apoc.es.put('localhost','neo4j_index','protocol','1',null,{number:'4',title:'title',type:'type'})  RETURN null"
                       ^}

Please tell what is wrong in the query.